# How to make a parent page for author.php?

Tags: php, query, html, author

by default I use the `author.php` template and it's working fine but I need to make a parent page for `author.php` like facebook and other social sites.

I want to do something like this:

```
site.com/author/trello/settings

site.com/author/trello/personalinformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this pages with new rewrite rules like that :

```
add_action("init", function () {

    add_rewrite_tag("%specialAuthor%", "([^&]+)");

    foreach (["personalinformation", "settings"] as $specialAuthor) {

        add_rewrite_rule(
              "author/([^/]+)/($specialAuthor)/?$"
            , "index.php?author_name=\$matches[1]&specialAuthor=\$matches[2]"
            , "top"
        );

    }

});


add_filter("author_template_hierarchy", function ($templates) {

    $specialAuthor = get_query_var("specialAuthor", NULL);

    if (isset($specialAuthor)) {

        $author = get_queried_object();

        $templates = [
            "$specialAuthor-{$author->user_nicename}.php",
            "$specialAuthor-{$author->ID}.php",
            "$specialAuthor.php",
        ];

    }

    return $templates;

});
```

the first time, flush the rewrite rules : 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

and after that, copy `author.php` to `personalinformation.php` in the theme for the URL `site.com/author/.../personalinformation`

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, I copy author.php to personalinformation.php and try to go to localhost/author/name/settings but it's got 404 error.

Comment: have you flushed the rewrite rules ? you can do that in the administration, "Settings" -> "Permalinks" and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Comment: Sorry, I forget this, I make this now and it's working yes but it's not getting the personalinformation.php content it's got an archive page for a custom post type, I hope you understand me.

Comment: Please be known that when i copy author.php to the custom post type archive file it's working without any problem and get the users the problem only that it's not getting the file that you choose (personalinformation.php).

Comment: my code add 2 endpoints. the endpoint `/settings` use `settings.php` and the the endpoint `/personalinformation` use `personalinformation.php`

Comment: Sorry, but I have a question how can check if the current page is settings.php? I try is_page_template function but it's not working.

Comment: where do you want to test that ?

Comment: I have undertstand your problem. it's good that you create this new question : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282897/change-author-template-hierarchy-filter

Comment: Thank you for answering my newest question, but what I asked to you here is different please let me explain to you, I want to make if condition the page is author/user/settings do something (i try if is_page_template but it's not working). I hope you understand me and thank you for your time.

Comment: ok then answer to my question : where do you want to test that ?

Comment: inside settings.php, and what about my newest question you will add another answer? thank you for your time :)

Comment: I know that i ask you so much but you can't help me?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress can't do that on its own. Author pages are only archives for users with published posts. What you need is more of a social network use for WordPress, and you should try BuddyPress plugin: [BuddyPress](https://buddypress.org/). It will create member pages for all users, and it will have different pages for each user: profile edit, profile view, settings... It might be more then you need, but that is closest to having profiles active.

There are other plugins for membership based website where you can have extensive profiles for users, you can find them on WordPress repository: [Members plugins on WP.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/members/).

Comment: I don't need to use any another membership plugin or BuddyPress my site is already a social network theme, so there's any another solution to make it work? This question really is very important for all.

Comment: If your theme is social network theme, it should already have membership area implemented, or it depends on some plugin to do so. You can either use an existing plugin or create a plugin that will do what you need. It can't be done with WordPress as it is, it requires a complex setup with the handling of custom pages you want each user to have, rewrite rules to expand urls...